# Field index only updated after merge

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have created a simple field index which looks like this:

- field name: root_test
- include root: false
- word lexicons: http://marklogic.com/collation/de/S1
- index settings: only word searches enabled
- Included Elements: A element `content`

I am creating a document with an element `content`  and two child-elements `header` and `body`. The second request uses the field index to find all values and test if it contains a word `Body`. As expected, it does. I am then updating my document without the `body` element and again requesting the field index words. The field index still contains the word `Body`. This is my test script:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

xdmp:document-insert("test.xml", 
  <test>
    <title>not found</title>
    <content>
      <header>Found</header>
      <body>Body</body>
    </content>
  </test>
);
fn:exists(fn:index-of(
  cts:field-words("root_test", (), ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/de/S1")), 
  "Body"
)) = fn:true();

xdmp:document-insert("test.xml", 
  <test>
    <title>not found</title>
    <content>
      <header>Found</header>
    </content>
  </test>
);
fn:empty(fn:index-of(
  cts:field-words("root_test", (), ("collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/de/S1")),
  "Body"
)) = fn:true()
```

I expected the following output:

```
true
true
```

But what I actually get is:

```
true
false
```

Only if I execute a manual **merge** after the update (second insert), the word `Body` gets removed from the field index.

Am I doing something wrong here? Using 9.0-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word lexicon doesn't keep track of specific document instances -- to do so would be prohibitively expensive -- and so it cannot purge information about deleted words until after a merge. Word lexicons on for query suggestion and to assist certain wildcard queries; you shouldn't count on them to provide precise information about the presence or absence of specific words in the corpus.

If want to know whether a specific word is in the corpus, do an estimate of a word query, e.g. `xdmp:estimate(cts:search(doc(),cts:word-query("Body",("unstemmed","case-insensitive","diacritic-insensitive"))))`. That won't give quite the same equality constraints as your collation, however, because search is codepoint based and doesn't fold compatibility characters and the like.